# Can not index raw binary data stored in Database in BLOB format in SOLR

Tags: solr, binary, apache-tika

We have raw binary data stored in database(not word,excel,xml etc files) in BLOB.
We are trying to index using TikaEntityProcessor but nothing seems to get indexed.
But the same configuration works when xml/word/excel files are stored in the BLOB field.
Below is our data-config.xml:

```
<dataSource name="db" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//a.a.a.a:a/d11gr21" user="abc" password="abc" convertType="true"/>

<dataSource name="dastream" type="FieldStreamDataSource" />
<document>
<entity 
  name="messages" pk=" PK" transformer='DateFormatTransformer'
  query="select * from table1"
  dataSource="db">
                    <field column =" PK" name ="id" />
            <field column="last_modified"  dateTimeFormat="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS" locale="en" />
<entity 
name="message"
    dataSource="dastream"
    processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
    url="message"
    dataField="messages.MESSAGE"
                            format="text"
    >
<field column="text" name="mxMsg" blob="true"/>
  </entity>
</entity>
```

Please suggest me the changes required to index binary data

Answer (score 0):

In Solr binary data can be indexed/query as Base64 encoded strings.

Comment: Any pointer how to achieve that?Can you put an example how the data-config.xml would look like.